# Android - Issues with Awaitility and Unit Testing

Tags: android, testing, junit

I have a pretty simple test. I'm waiting for a list of transactions to be received and assigned to a list view.

```
@Test
fun testTransactionsLoad(){
    val listView: ListView? = fragment!!.findView(R.id.listView)

    assertNotNull(listView)

    await().atMost(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until(transactionsLoad(listView!!))

    assert(listView.adapter.count > 0)
}
```

But for some reason, awaitability always send false for this callable:

```
private fun transactionsLoad(listView: ListView): Callable<Boolean> {
    return if (listView.adapter == null){
        Callable { false }
    } else {
        Callable { true }
    }
}
```

It's not the first time Awaitility returns the wrong thing. On my device, the list view loads, proving it should also have an adapter. The adapter still appears as null in the callable though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using kotlin, you could do:

```
await().atMost(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).until{ listView.adapter != null }
```